# Why is it necessary to include x.h in x.cpp if x.h consists only of a function declaration

Tags: c++

Why is it necessary to include *x.h* in *x.cpp* if *x.h* consists only of a function declaration? Or can you never do this?

Comment: Show a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Because that's the language syntax rules.

Comment: Don't you *want* the compiler to check that the declarations and definitions match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// x.h
void f();

// x.cpp
void f() { }
```

There's nothing in x.cpp that depends on the contents of x.h. You don't need to `#include "x.h"`.

```
// x.h
void f()

// x.cpp
int f() { return 0; }
```

Here, the definition in x.cpp conflicts with x.h. The compiler would see this if x.cpp had `#include "x.h"` at the top and give you an error message.

```
// x.h
struct x { };

// x.cpp
x f() { x my_x; return my_x; }
```

Here, the definition of `x` in the header is needed by the code in x.cpp. The code needs `#include "x.h"` in order to compile. (Yes, you could repeat the definition of `struct x` in x.cpp without using a `#include` directive, and the code would be correct if the definition of `struct x` in x.cpp was correct; using the header ensures that the definition is the same, without having to keep multiple copies of the definition in sync).

In summary: you don't have to include the header if it's not needed. But in general it's a good idea, because it might result in the compiler catching errors, and sooner or later it probably will be needed. When I'm implementing something new, I create the header file, then write the first version of x.cpp:

```
// x.cpp
#include "x.h"
```

Compiling this source file will catch syntax errors in x.h.

Answer (score 0):

From the C++ Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/header-files-cpp?view=vs-2019):

> To minimize the potential for errors, C++ has adopted the convention
>   of using **header files to contain declarations**. You make the
>   declarations in a header file, then use the #include directive in
>   every .cpp file or other header file that requires that declaration.
>   **The #include directive inserts a copy of the header file directly into
>   the .cpp file prior to compilation**.

However, you could also put all the declarations in the source file instead of using header files because (but then you'll have lots of duplicated code i.e. function declarations):

> When you compile a program, each .cpp file is compiled independently
>   into a compilation unit. The compiler has no knowledge of what names
>   are declared in other compilation units. That means that if you define
>   a class or function or global variable, you must provide a declaration
>   of that thing in each additional .cpp file that uses it.

So, you can never have header files but then you would need to put function declaration in every source file that uses that function. In case you have more than one function declaration, this would  result in having lots of duplicated code. Therefore, it is strongly suggested to make use of header files.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use headerfiles, though doing it is strongly recommended.
You could duplicate all the declarations manually instead, copy-and-paste never really went out of style despite the drawbacks.

Also, you don't have to include the corresponding headerfile (first) in your implementation file, most of the declarations should be duplicated in the definitions there.
Not doing so removes an important sanity-check which helps uncover fatal inconsistencies though.

Answer (score 0):

Even if everything works without this, it is useful for the compiler to verify that the declarations and definitions match.

Comment: If the declaration and the definition don't match, the compiler will silently assume that you overloaded the function.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Depends on how you define it http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aceb24dcd35c781